# Why does PHP DATE_ADD() function returns a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, dateadd

Im trying to populate a table using some other specific tables(there's a set of tables known as table_1,table_2,table_3 etc) in the same database by giving a date interval(to obtain rows which are recorded within a month). below is the code im using

```
<?php
include("functions.php");
connect();
$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name LIKE 'mytable_%'");



$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table_count);
$loop_var = ($row["cnt"]);


for ($x=1; $x<=$loop_var; $x++) {


mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats (`useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, `timestamp`)
SELECT `useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, `timestamp` FROM table_'.$x.'
WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

but at the moment this returns as errror saying

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''.1.' WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)' at line 2

can anybody help on me soughting this out

Comment: `echo` your query to see that `FROM table_'.$x.'` part is evaluated to not what you expect

Comment: thank you for the response i will check!!

Comment: i tried echo table_$x; but it gives an error saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''$x'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in ...

Comment: Echo your **whole query** as you pass it to the `mysql_query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats (`useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, `timestamp`)
SELECT `useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, `timestamp` FROM table_$x
WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

or

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats (`useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, `timestamp`)
SELECT `useragent_browser`, `useragent_OS`, `timestamp` FROM table_".$x."
WHERE `timestamp` > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)") or die(mysql_error());
}
```